# tabcmd refreshextracts with hyper api : error 80030

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to do refreshextracts using hyperfiles but i am receiving error on 80030 , i was wondering if this is possible to refreshextracts with hyper api

This is using on tableau command prompt.

example script is as shown

```
tabcmd refreshextracts --datasource data_1 -s https://..../ --no-certcheck --no-prompt --no-proxy -username test -password abc /tmp/newhyper.hyper
```

data_1 = is the current datasource , /tmp/newhyper.hyper = is new table
i was wondering if this is possible with tabcmd

Comment: Please check if you have a live connection or an extract connection. With live connection, of course, you can't refresh extract.

Comment: I have extract connection but it seems i am unable to do a refresh extract, my datasource are in hyper files